# MySQL SELECT Statement Only Returns One Row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

It's been quite a long time since I last asked a question, but I've been stumped messing with SQL in an attempt to build my own forum system.

The background of my problem is that I'm trying to create a function to display the most popular threads based on how many replies it has and how recent the latest reply was.

With some reading, I made this SQL statement.

```
SELECT 
topics.id, 
topics.authorID,
topics.lastReply
FROM 
ms_topics as topics
INNER JOIN
(SELECT inTopic FROM ms_posts) as rcount
ON
rcount.inTopic = topics.id
ORDER BY
topics.lastReply DESC,
count(rcount.inTopic)
```

And then I use PDO's `fetchAll()` function to bring the results into a variable.

```
$GetPopular = $db->prepare('SQL Statement Above');
$GetPopular->execute();
$Populars = $GetPopular->fetchAll();
```

And, in an effort to trouble shoot, I use `var_dump()` on `$populars`, which returns only one row from the database.

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "4" ["authorID"]=> string(1) "1" ["lastReply"]=> string(19) "2014-06-08 19:49:50" } }
```

My question is basically this; why would it not be returning more than one row, and how do I make it do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track with the joined subquery, but you need to apply the `COUNT()` *inside* the subquery. Otherwise, the aggregate group is applied to the outer query, resulting in one row.

This is because you have no `GROUP BY`, which MySQL is lenient about. It gives you one row back with not quite the results you expect, where most other RDBMS would give you a parse error.  Otherwise, an aggregate function (`COUNT(),MIN(),MAX(),SUM()`, etc) with no `GROUP BY` will never result in more than one row returned.

```
SELECT 
  topics.id, 
  topics.authorID,
  topics.lastReply,
  postsInTopic
FROM 
  ms_topics as topics
  /* The subquery provides the aggregate count
     grouped per inTopic */
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
     inTopic,
     COUNT(*) AS postsInTopic
   FROM ms_posts
   GROUP BY inTopic
  ) as rcount ON rcount.inTopic = topics.id
ORDER BY
  topics.lastReply DESC,
  /* Use the alias from the subquery postsInTopic to srot */
  postsInTopic
```

A quick note about PDO and `prepare()`:  While it is *a good thing* that it's in your workflow, it is not strictly necessary to use `prepare()/execute()` if your query has no input values (no dynamic `WHERE` clause, for example).  For a static query in a case like this, you can safely call [`PDO::query()`](https://www.php.net//manual/en/pdo.query.php) with less overhead and a little less code.